# When add something right to navigation, Part of Navigation bar is not working

Tags: html, css

I want to add some boxes in body, but some bar of navigation specifically parallel to the boxes is not working.

```css
    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 160px;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .5s;
    transition: transform .4s;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
    background-color: #bddf95;
    line-height: 70px;
}
nav .logo {
    float: left;
}
nav.black{
    background: rgb(0,0,0,.8);
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
}
nav.black .logo img{
    height: 60px;
    transition: .5s;
}
nav .logo img{
    height: 80px;
    transition: .5s; 
}
nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
nav.black ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
}
nav ul li a{
    line-height: 80px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Roboto' sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    transition: .5s;
}
nav.black ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #4cd137;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
#sidebar{
    height: 100%;
    width: 220px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#sidebar ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 3px solid #555;
    background-color: #bddf95;
}
#sidebar ul li{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#sidebar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}
#sidebar ul li:hover,#sidebar ul li:hover a{
    color: white;
    padding-left:10px;
    background: #4cd137;
    transition:.3s all ease;
}
#cbox {
    margin-left: 530px; 
    margin-top: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -3;
}
#cbox ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family: roboto;
}
#cbox ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
#soil {
    margin-left: : 5px;
    margin-right: 15px; 
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background: #bddf75;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
    padding: 50px;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
}
#coil {
    margin-left: : 5px;
    margin-right: 15px; 
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
    padding: 50px;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
}
#other {
    margin-left: : 5px;
    margin-right: 15px; 
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
    padding: 50px;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/all.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/buy.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="project_pic/logo-png.png">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">General Ledger</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Seller</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Buyer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Owener</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Leader</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id ="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>     Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dungeon"></i>     Sell Bricks</a></li>
                <li><a href="buy.html"><i class="fa fa-calendar-plus"></i>     Buy Something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i>     Daily Calculation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book"></i>     Sales Journal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book"></i>     Purchase Journal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i>     Balance Sheet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-male"></i>     Daily Labor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>     Admin Setting</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="cbox">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="soil">Soil</a></li>
            <li><a href="coil.html" id="coil">Coil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="other">Others</a></li>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, 3rd, 4th and 5th bar is not working. if i changes top margin than another three will be affected parallel to the boxes. I tried different z-index on box but that does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by removing `z-index:-1` from `#sidebar`. You can give your nav a z-index:1 to cover the top of the sidebar, so the appearance remains the same.